# Windows 8 partition deleted after install ubuntu 14.04.1!

Tags: partitioning, testdisk

My friend have laptop, and he downloaded and burned Ubuntu 14.04.1 iso on flash, and he  install Ubuntu from flash, but he accidently erasing every things and all partitions, and install ubuntu on one partition with all space

i tried to recover partition with testdisk but with no hope :(

and try to recover all files and data by testdisk, but also no hope

any help to recover data from hard disk by testdisk with right way?

Comment: Data recovery is complex and outlined here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery . In general, start with photrec / testdisk. If those do not work, consider professional help. If the data was over written it may be lost. In general, please keep backups of your valuable data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get anything with testdisk.

but with photorec, I get much of unorganized files, and i think not all of data